# UIView animateWithDuration not getting executed

Tags: ios

I am trying to move a UIView from the bottom to the top.
I am using iOS SDK 7.0, the uiviewcontroller's autolayout is on.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: myView];
    [self moveFromBottom];

}

- (void) moveFromBottom{
    [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    CGPoint top =  myView.center;
    top.y = self.view.frame.size.height - top.y;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         myView.center = top;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {
                             NSLog(@"finished");
                         }
                     }
     ];
```

The completion block gets executed and print finish but the UIView is not moved.

I also tried animate frame instead of center, which does not work neither.

But if I try to animate alpha instead it will work

edit: if I turn off autolayout in the storyboard it will also work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot explicitly set the frame or center when Autolayout is turned on. My suggestion would be to create an IBOutlet for the y-origin constraint on myView and set the `constant` property of that in your animation block. That should animate properly.

Comment: Where can I find y-origin constraint? I know there are height and top/bottom space to superview constraints that can control y.

Comment: The top to superview constraint is the one you want. If the view's height is static, you don't need a bottom to superview constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Where is myView initially? If it is dead center:

```
top.y = self.view.frame.size.height - top.y;
```

will be equal to the initial value of top.y. so it will not move. Did you mean to move it flush to the top. If so I think it should be:

```
top.y = (myView.frame.size.height/2.0f);
```

Also if you have auto layout enabled, check what constraints you have and make sure its not forcing it to pin in its position. I would disable auto layout to make sure this is not causing your issue. If all else fails, NSLog the value of top.y to make sure its what you intended.

Comment: No top.y and the center.y of myView is very different